# jQuery cant get value from textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to get a value from a textbox so that that I can rotate an Image using jQuery

```
<script src="Scripts/jQueryRotate.2.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   var angle = $("input:TextBox1").val();
    $("#needle").rotate(angle);
    alert(angle);
});
</script>
```

And I'm populating the textbox as follows

```
<script runat="server">
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  { 
     WeatherLibrary.WeatherData wLib = new WeatherLibrary.WeatherData();
     double dataLatest;
     string sensorName;
     sensorName = "umtAdjWinDir";
     double dir = wLib.GetLatestData(sensorName).Value;
     dir = Math.Round(dir, 0);
     TextBox1.Text = dir.ToString();

   }
</script>
```

TextBox1 is the the id of the textbox

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

The alert I have given says `undefined` and the image never gets rotated.

Comment: Try this `$("#TextBox1")` instead of this `$("input:TextBox1")`

Comment: Can we see your html? This is a little vague

Comment: are you using master page or user control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var angle = $("#TextBox1").val();
```

OR

```
var angle = $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").val();
```

Answer (score 2):

If TextBox1 is the id of the input element you can use `var angle = $("#TextBox1").val();` to get the value form the textbox

Answer (score 1):

Try using :

```
   var angle = $('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var angle = $("input#TextBox1").val();
```

assuming you have an input with id="TextBox1"

Answer (score 0):

I think not sure it may be a problem of master page or user control.

Comment: what can be the problem with master page?

Comment: if you put you control on master page the id of the control changes. If you are using asp.net 4.0 or greater you can use Client ID to static

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="Scripts/jQueryRotate.2.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {



       var angle = $("#TextBox1").val();
        $("#needle").rotate(angle);
        alert(angle);

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposed to be

```
var angle = $("input[id*='TextBox1']").val();  // For ID

var angle = $("input.TextBox1").val();  // For class

var angle = $("[id*='TextBox1']").val();  // For ID this is sufficient
```

Need to use `attribute ends with $` or `attribute contains selector *` if you are using **ASP.NET** controls with `runat="server"` attribute

Answer (score 0):

$("#TextBox1").val() this code will help u out to get the textbox value..